# Spark-Scala RDD[(String, Int)] immutable error

Tags: apache-spark

I wanted to process a csv file which is of below format,

```
Tran-Date, Reference-Id, Payee, Address, Amount
2016/02/22,34343432, Wawa, Malvern, -10.51
2016/01/12,34343411, Exon, Malvern, -30.67
2016/03/02,34343999, Wawa, Malvern, -19.23
```

and my desired output is as follows,

```
wawa, -29.74
Exon, -30.67
```

I did the following in the Spark-Shell,

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("/file/source")
val payeeAmountMap = textFile.map(lines => {val line = lines.split(","); 
(line(2), line(4).toInt)})
```

The immediate above command resulted in the RDD[(String, Int)]

The problem is, I am not able to print this RDD or do any action on this RDD.

Please advise how to proceed further to achieve the desired output.

Note:- I am new Spark world. Any advise would help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can post the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want some output, you need an action. For example

```
payeeAmountMap.take(5)
```

As far as your desired output, you need to group by the Payee and apply a sum aggregate function over the Amount column

Note: Spark SQL and the spark-csv library would help you more than manually splitting yourself on commas and using RDD functions